# Get Complete URL

Tags: windows, ubuntu, software-rec, url

I would like ask how to get full url address (even "GET" request type or any other types). 
Does it have any software for Windows or Ubuntu users?
Initial link is that: "http://www.eclass.inha.uz"
But  I need to get "http://eclass.inha.uz/servlet/controller.homepage.MainServlet?p_process=main&p_grcode=N000001". It doest not matter which language is being used. I need result.

I am able to get complete url with Wireshark software, but " http.request.type == "POST" ".

Comment: Get the full address *of what*? A website? Are you programming a browser extension? Writing javascript for a website? You're not very clear. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Your question sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029). What do you need it for? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you give, `http://www.eclass.inha.uz`, does not resolve. However, if you strip off the initial `www.`, it does resolve, and does indeed redirect as you say it does. cURL can show redirects, but it might be tricky in this specific case, as it's a javascript redirect, not a `Location` header:

```
$ curl -v http://eclass.inha.uz
* Rebuilt URL to: http://eclass.inha.uz/
*   Trying 195.158.19.238...
* Connected to eclass.inha.uz (195.158.19.238) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: eclass.inha.uz
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 250
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=01A873B139B6FF2EF66B81C0D2540AD9; Path=/
< X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2019 22:51:17 GMT
< 


<html>
<head>

<Script Language='JavaScript'>
<!--
        var portNumber = "";


    document.location.replace("/servlet/controller.homepage.MainServlet?p_process=main&p_grcode=N000001");
//-->
</Script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You might be able to parse something out of that.

For example,

```
$ curl -s http://eclass.inha.uz | grep document.location.replace | cut -d '"' -f2
/servlet/controller.homepage.MainServlet?p_process=main&p_grcode=N000001
```